# How to show zero result when user search with Dot in search field in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

In a wordpress site if You search with a dot(.) character. Wordpress will show all post and pages in result but I want to show Zero result when a user search with dot(.) character in wordpress search query.

Please suggest me How can I do this work without plugin's help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
function post_filter_func($query) {

    if (! is_admin()  && $query->is_main_query()  && $query->is_search()) {

        $search_query = $query->query_vars['s'];

        if($search_query =='.'){
             $query->set('post_type', array('none-post'));
             $query->set('s', '');
             unset( $query->query['s'] );
             $query->is_search = FALSE;
        }
    }
      return $query;
};

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'post_filter_func' );
```

Comment: let me check sir

Comment: George your answer is appreciable but it solve my half problem. After adding this code my search showing only post result but I want to prevent posts by searhing dot(.) keyword

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: I want to show zero result when someone put dot(.) in search box because dot(.) gives whole posts and pages. and this is wordpress default functionality

Comment: george it is working for "?s=." not for "?search=."  when I search through second one It give me result but I want to prevent this also

Comment: you can add the condition in `if`

like if($search_query =='.' || $_REQUEST['search']=='.')

Comment: Thanks George for your suggestion but it's not working. still result is showing by dot(.)

Comment: can you share me the site url?

Comment: george its done Thanks for your valuable time and answer :)